# For loop does not update index as I read file

Tags: python

I am trying to read a file using Python. I want to take the values that follow 'Average Value' and 'Standard Deviation' after the term 'DISTRIBUTION OF OFFSET_0' in a list that can be put in CSV file for analysis.

A part of the file is given below.

```
  DISTRIBUTION OF BLB_FLIP_0
      * NOMINAL VALUE =  5.0000E-01
      * AVERAGE VALUE =  5.0000E-01
      * STANDARD DEVIATION =  0.0          ( 0.0%)
      * STANDARD DEVIATION BASED ON NOMINAL RUN =  0.0          ( 0.0%)
    DISTRIBUTION OF OFFSET_0
      * NOMINAL VALUE =  4.0000E-03
      * AVERAGE VALUE =  1.4000E-02
      * STANDARD DEVIATION =  1.9987E-02   (142.8%)
      * STANDARD DEVIATION BASED ON NOMINAL RUN =  2.0484E-02   (512.1%)

EXTRACT for TRANSIENT ANALYSIS
  PARAM TEMP = -4.0000E+01
  PARAM VH =  1.3200E+00
  TEMPERATURE = -4.0000E+01 Celsius
    *T_OUT_F10_0  =  4.0302E-04
    *BL_FLIP_0    =  1.1210E+00
    *BLB_FLIP_0   =  1.1200E+00
    *OFFSET_0     =  1.0000E-03
    DISTRIBUTION OF T_OUT_F10_0
      * NOMINAL VALUE =  4.0302E-04
      * AVERAGE VALUE =  4.3982E-04
      * STANDARD DEVIATION =  3.5741E-05   ( 8.1%)
      * STANDARD DEVIATION BASED ON NOMINAL RUN =  4.8746E-05   (12.1%)
    DISTRIBUTION OF BL_FLIP_0
      * NOMINAL VALUE =  1.1210E+00
      * AVERAGE VALUE =  1.1394E+00
      * STANDARD DEVIATION =  1.7869E-02   ( 1.6%)
      * STANDARD DEVIATION BASED ON NOMINAL RUN =  2.4372E-02   ( 2.2%)
    DISTRIBUTION OF BLB_FLIP_0
      * NOMINAL VALUE =  1.1200E+00
      * AVERAGE VALUE =  1.1200E+00
      * STANDARD DEVIATION =  0.0          ( 0.0%)
      * STANDARD DEVIATION BASED ON NOMINAL RUN =  0.0          ( 0.0%)
    DISTRIBUTION OF OFFSET_0
      * NOMINAL VALUE =  1.0000E-03
      * AVERAGE VALUE =  1.9400E-02
      * STANDARD DEVIATION =  1.7869E-02   (92.1%)
      * STANDARD DEVIATION BASED ON NOMINAL RUN =  2.4372E-02   (2437.2%)
```

However, when I run the following python code, I realised the value is stuck at the first time the loop finds 'DISTRIBUTION OF OFFSET_0' that is the index does not change as I read the file array. I am unable to determine the error. Any lead appreciated.

```
import csv
import numpy as np
i_file = open ("setup.aex", "r")

file_matrix = i_file.readlines()
#print (file_matrix)


mean = []
sd = []

for i in file_matrix:
        print(file_matrix.index (i))
        if ('DISTRIBUTION OF OFFSET_0' in i) & ('AVERAGE VALUE' in (file_matrix.index(i)+2)):
                print(file_matrix.index(i))
                mean_loc = file_matrix[(file_matrix.index(i))+2]
                mean_el = float(mean_loc.split ("AVERAGE VALUE = ")[1])
                print (mean_el)
                mean.append(mean_el)

                sd_loc = file_matrix[(file_matrix.index(i))+3]
                sd_inter =sd_loc.split (" * STANDARD DEVIATION = ")[1]
                sd_el = float (sd_inter.split ("   (")[0])
                print (sd_el)
                sd.append(sd_el)


print (mean)
print (sd)
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How about [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)?

Comment: BTW, are you really sure you want to use `&` instead of `and`? They're not the same thing.

Comment: As Olvin said: You are currently iterating over `readlines()`, so `i` is the text in the line. In case you have multiple lines with the same text, it'll return the first one found. Using enumerate would allow you to keep your current index

Comment: `index(item)` gives always index for first `item` on the list. It would need `index(item, start_position)` to get index for first item after `start_position` - so you maun ened something like `index(item, previous_index+1)` but more popular is to use `enumerate` - `for index, item in enumerate(file_matrix)` and you don't need `index()`

Comment: Thank you so much, folks. I analysed the code for about an hour, but couldn't recall that index provides only first location. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can fix your code according to the comments. In case you want to take this project any further, I've made a more streamlined version to get the data. It gradually consumes the input and returns you a dictionary with all the data in it.

```py
import json

i_file = open ("log.log", "r")
data = {}

def linevalue(line):
    name, value = line.split("=")
    name = name.replace("*", "").strip()
    value = value.strip()
    return name, value

try:
    while line := next(i_file):
        indent = len(line) - len(line.lstrip())
        line = line.strip()
        is_value = "=" in line

        if indent == 0 and len(line.strip()) > 0:
            title = line
            data[title] = {}

        elif (indent == 2 or indent == 4) and is_value:
            name, value = linevalue(line)
            data[title][name] = value

        elif indent == 4: #is a title
            name = line
            data[title][name] = {}
            for i in range(4):
                line = next(i_file)
                sub_name, sub_value = linevalue(line)
                data[title][name][sub_name] = sub_value
except StopIteration: 
    pass
finally:
    del i_file

with open("output.json", "w") as fp:
    json.dump(data, fp)
```